# &quot characters when I import data to SAS

Tags: sas, substr, quote

I have the following data in Excel and I am trying to create a few variables using SAS

```
    Data

    Id   Amount   date              Text
    101    5000    2/12/2019        <xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><icd:Envelope...
```

I used the following code to import

```
   proc import datafile='c:\Data.xlsx' DBMS=xlsx out=clean replace;run;
```

I am seeing some junk data in my `Clean` dataset. Is there a way to avoid this?

```
     &quot:0&quot encoding=&quot
```

Comment: I tried your code with your example, no junks for me. I have SAS EG 7.15 64bits. What is yours ? Have you any options before the code ?

Comment: I just figured out that its the excel file formatting issue. I had open it and do "save as" then it worked. Thanks

Comment: What did you save it as ?

Comment: @ckp Was your file .xls and then you saved it as xlsx ?